# Appending Row with Script Changes Text-Formatted Value to Time-Formatted Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, append

Using the script below, numbers formatted as text are being changed to time format, even though I have Column E2:E in Logged_Data sheet formatted as "Plain text".  What is the reason for this? And what can I do to fix it?

In Data_Input!D8, the cell is formatted as "Plain text":

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

However, when it appears on the Logged_Data sheet, it is formatted as time:

[image: Screenshot3]

Here is the script I am using:

```
function transposeAndAppend() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let shtIn = ss.getSheetByName("Data_Input");
  let shtOut = ss.getSheetByName("Logged_Data");

  let responses = shtIn.getRange("D4:D11").getValues();
  //responses is a 2d array that looks like this [[a],[b],[c]]
  
  //first transpose it
  let transResp = responses[0].map((resp,i)=>responses.map(r => r[i]))
  //we now have [[a,b,c]] 

  shtOut.appendRow(transResp.flat())

    //Clear the 'form'
  shtIn.getRange("D4:D11").clearContent();
}
```

According to Hyde at Google Support, https://support.google.com/docs/thread/99094988/can-you-format-the-data-when-doing-appendrow?hl=en, this should not be happening.

Comment: In your situation, can I ask you about the number format of `Data_Input!D4:11`? I'm worried that the modification point might depend on the number format of `Data_Input!D4:11`. For example, if you want to copy the values and format of `Data_Input!D4:11` to the last row of "Logged_Data", when your `shtIn` and `shtOut` in your script are used, `shtIn.getRange("D4:D11").copyTo(shtOut.getRange(shtOut.getLastRow() + 1, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true)` might be able to be used. But, I'm not sure your actual Spreadsheet. So, I proposed it as a comment. I apologize for this.

Comment: This does not work as it does not transpose the values in D4:D11.  In regard to your question about number format, all values in D4:D11 are formatted as "Plain text."  The reason I did this was because people entering values in D8 would enter, for example, 5:20 for five minutes and twenty seconds, but the spreadsheet would read that input as 5 hours and 20 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `This does not work as it does not transpose the values in D4:D11.`, I have to apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested `shtIn.getRange("D4:D11").copyTo(shtOut.getRange(shtOut.getLastRow() + 1, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true)` using sample values of "D4:D11" with `In regard to your question about number format, all values in D4:D11 are formatted as "Plain text."`, the values are put into columns "A" to "H" as the text format.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate it. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? For example, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating `This does not work as it does not transpose the values in D4:D11.`? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: My Data_Input sheet operates like a form.  User puts values (formatted as "Plain text") in cells D4:D11.  My script transposes this range of values and appends them to a new row on Logged_Data sheet.  However. despite the fact that I also have the columns in Logged_Data sheet formatted as strings, the value entered in D8 as X:XX to signify minutes and seconds is getting changed to a time format on Logged_Data sheet in column E.  I wish for it to remain as "Plain text".

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, I try to correctly replicate your situation. But, unfortunately, I cannot still replicate `This does not work as it does not transpose the values in D4:D11.`. Unfortunately, the values of "D4:D11" of "Data_Input" are appended into columns "A" to "H" of "Logged_Data" as the text format. But, I would like to try to correctly replicate it. If I could correctly replicate it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: `shtIn.getRange("D4:D11").copyTo(shtOut.getRange(shtOut.getLastRow() + 1, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true)` the range does get entered correctly.  However, I changed `PASTE_NORMAL` to `PASTE_VALUES` thus getting rid of borders, large text size, etc.  So thank you.  Can you propose that as your answer so I can accept?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood your reply. Also, I understood that in your situation, `PASTE_VALUES` is better than `PASTE_NORMAL`. From your reply, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to append the values from "D4:D11" of "Data_Input" sheet to columns "A" to "H" of "Logged_Data" sheet.
- The number format of "D4:D11" of "Data_Input" is the plain text.

I would like to propose using the [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed) method of Class Range. The modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script.

```js
function transposeAndAppend() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let shtIn = ss.getSheetByName("Data_Input");
  let shtOut = ss.getSheetByName("Logged_Data");

  // I modified the below script.
  const srcRange = shtIn.getRange("D4:D11");
  const dstRange = shtOut.getRange(shtOut.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, true);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed)

Answer (score 0):

You could try transposing the numberformats along with the data.

```
function transposeAndAppend() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let shtIn = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let shtOut = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let responses = shtIn.getRange("D4:D11").getValues();
  let formats = shtIn.getRange("D4:D11").getNumberFormats();
  let transResp = responses[0].map((resp, i) => responses.map(r => r[i]));
  let transForm = formats[0].map((f,i) => formats.map(r => r[i]));//get numberformats
  shtOut.getRange(shtOut.getLastRow() + 1, 1, transResp.length,transResp[0].length).setValues(transResp);
  shtOut.getRange(shtOut.getLastRow(), 1, transForm.length, transForm[0].length).setNumberFormats(transForm);//set transformed numberformats
  shtIn.getRange("D4:D11").clearContent();
}
```

- [Range.getNumberFormats()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumberformats)
- [Range.setNumberFormats](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatsnumberformats)

Comment: Oddly enough, all the data from Data_Input!D4:11 is appended correctly in Logged_Data except for the data that was in Data_Input!D8.  The cell in Logged_Data that corresponds to the value in Data_Input!D8 appears blank.  When I click on the cell, the value is 0.208333333333333.  The value that I put in Data_Input!D8 was 5:00.

Comment: Do you mean Data_Input!D4:D11?

Comment: No.  I mean Data_Input!D8.  Every other value that I put in Data_Input!D4:D11 appended correctly on the Logged_Data sheet.  The value of 5:00 in Data_Input!D8 was appended as  0.208333333333333 in Logged_Data sheet.  The cell appears blank, but when I click on the cell, this is the value displayed.